# Building a Dockerimage to run an executable

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've tried a number of things, i made a post on reddit also. Just looking for a direction, i've checked out every link that comes up from a google search of the error but nothing of value showed up.

reddit post
https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/p1vj30/building_a_dockerfile_that_executes_and_exe/

Current Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:10.0.19042.1110-amd64
WORKDIR /TestFolder
COPY ./Binaries/ /TestFolder 
ENTRYPOINT [ "/TestFolder/ColorConsole.exe" ] 
CMD [ "--help" ]
```

CLI ERROR:

> container
> 43a2965b0a522aa8e34d4b418dbe62b9910df96412a88e52b740a9cdb9235052
> encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in
> a Windows system call: The requested virtual machine or container
> operation is not valid in the current state. (0xc0370105)

LOG OUTPUT:

> Error response from daemon: configured logging driver does not support
> reading

Comment: Is your docker host a Windows or Linux machine? Windows images can't run on Linux (and vice versa).

Comment: ColorConsole.exe is build with .NET Framework or .NET Core ?

Comment: it's running on windows, and it's just a c++ no .NET

Comment: Can you run any containers at all?

Comment: Yes, i can run the hello world container, actually i've run another one also. just not one with an exe in it.